# Почему не работает mvn clean?

Tags: java, maven

при запуске mvn clean зависает на этом моменте:

```
D:\development\projects\learn-maven\first>mvn clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO]   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Simple Maven 2 Artifact 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

запуск с параметром -X зависает на стадии site:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Simple Maven 2 Artifact 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-source
, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resour
age, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integrat
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
```

pom.xml:

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/pom/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/pom/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>bioker</groupId>
    <artifactId>testartifact1</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Simple Maven 2 Artifact</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: отоедактируйте вопрос с "Править" и поставьте сообшении в текстовом виде

Comment: было бы неплохо увидеть ваш pom файл

Comment: @Vartlok добваил

Comment: а что происходит при запуске других таргетов? например `mvn validate` ?